# how to dump aws lambda payload on failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

i have lambda which creates cloudwatch alarm when it fails. The cloudwatch alarm is redirected to sns topic.How do I dump the payload content to sns when lambda fails.
I am not sure if I can DLQ as my lambda is event driven and gets triggered based on some particular events

Comment: can you not directly push to sns from lambda when it fails?

Comment: If lambda fails how  is it suppose to push to sns.